# PHP: Draw a line on image

Tags: php, return, break

```
for($c = 0; $c < $count-1; $c++){

$combine = $path[$c].$path[$c+1];

switch($combine){
    case "13":
        imagelinethick($img,1000,1000,500,500,$red,$thick=20);
        return(imagepng($img));
        break;
    case "36":
        imagelinethick($img,1000,1000,1200,1500,$red,$thick=20);
        return(imagepng($img));
        break;
    case "65":
        imagelinethick($img,1200,1500,3500,200,$red,$thick=20);
        return(imagepng($img));
        break;
    default:
        echo "hehehe";
    }
}
```

Inside the `$path = array() is 1365`

And I am trying to draw a line on an image. The problem is whenever it finds a case it the whole loop stops. Does `return()` can break a loop ? Any suggestions to improve this work ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: return stops the function from executing further. why dont you remove all returns and just put one right above the final `}` ?

Comment: I think you should replace your return statements with`$img=imagepng($img);`

Comment: @JapanGuy that did it. thank you